# GNU Smalltalk - Break from whileTrue loop without return

Tags: loops, while-loop, break, smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

What is a simple and concise way to break from a `whileTrue` loop in GNU Smalltalk that doesn't require returning?

Here is my code. I want to break from the loop at Line 31 at the end if `char_stack` is empty.

https://gist.github.com/SYZYGY-DEV333/ea3f5eeb3473927c8faa294bb72a8858

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the [articles of the Byte magazine](https://archive.org/details/byte-magazine-1981-08/page/n343/mode/2up?view=theater) (1982) titled **Building Control Structures in the Smalltalk-80 System** by *Peter Deutsch* , shows how easy is to implement while-loop breaks for **infrequent events** that might happen inside the loop.

To implement this we only need a new class and an extension to `BlockClosure`, making a total of **9 lines of code**(!).

**The class**: `BlockWithExit`, subclass of `Object` with two ivars `exit` and `block` and the following methods

```
on: aBlock
  block := aBlock

value
  exit := [^nil].
  ^block value

exit
  exit value
```

**Extension**

```
BlockClosure>>withExit
  ^BlockWithExit new on: self
```

and that's it!

**Example**

Find the max of a collection until its exhaustion or until `nil` is found (the *infrequent event*)

```
maxBeforeNil: aCollection
  | max supplier loop |
  max := 0.
  supplier := aCollection readStream.
  loop := [
    [supplier atEnd]
      whileFalse: [
        value := supplier next.
        value isNil ifTrue: [loop exit].
        max := max max: value]] withExit.
  loop value.
  ^max
```

**Why does this work the way it does?** Because *a block with a non-local return exits from the method that defines the block*.

In this case this method is `BlockWithExit>>value`, therefore when `[^nil]` is evaluated from `loop exit`, the flow exits `value` and goes to its sender, right after `loop value`.

The outstanding corollary of Deutsch's discovery is that **the whole mechanism of** `Exceptions` **can be built using this very same trick** of defining an exit block in an ivar like: `exit := [^nil]`.

Comment: So, if the code was `value isNil ifTrue: [^nil]` instead, it would just return from that block itself but will still continue in the `whileFalse` block right?

Comment: No. Any explicit return inside the block exits from the method where the block is textually defined. With your modification the control would have passed to the sender of `maxBeforeNil:`.

Comment: Oh that's true and the whole execution would be nil, whereas with this it would return whatever value `max` has at that point.

Comment: That's exactly right.

Answer (score 5):

In general, Smalltalk does not have a way of breaking from a loop, except for returning from the enclosing method.

Try to extract your loop into another method from which you can return to break from the loop.

In a way, Smalltalk the language does not even have loops... but some methods happen to evaluate blocks more than once. Hence it does not have a special way to terminate "loops". Return is the way.

If you have not already done so, familiarize yourself with the different iteration methods of Collection: `do:`, `select:`, `collect:`, `detect:ifNone:`, ... The latter is another way to run an "incomplete" loop over a collection, but it does not solve all cases in which you might wish for a "break".

Comment: Thanks for the assistance and thorough answer. I'll keep that stuff in mind.